# How to make annotations over a PDF?

Tags: pdf, tablet, pen

I use Foxit Pdf Reader and I also have a Trust pen tablet that I use mostly with a software called SmoothDraw. I was wondering if there is a way that I could open a pdf and write annotations over it by using my pen tablet; is there any way to do this?